# Add the squares of the first 20 numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is what I have:

```
def add_squares(start, end):
   for n in range(start, end):
print(n**2 + n**2)
```

I want to add the squares of numbers from 1-20

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
def add_vals(start, stop):
    return sum(i**2 for i in range(start, stop))

print(add_vals(1, 21))
```

Output:

```
2870
```

Comment: @TomKarzes is efficiency the issue with `pow(i, 2)`?

Comment: More like clarity of expression.  You simply don't need a function in this context.  The `**` operator exists for a reason.

Comment: @TomKarzes Noted. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: @Ajax1234 `**` is a syntax construct, whereas `pow` requires a function call resolution, so is slightly slower. Otherwise, they have the same complexity.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ good to know, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to store the square of each number somewhere.

```
def add_square(start, end):
    result = 0 
    for i in range(start, end+1):
        result += i**2
    print(result)
```

Result: 2870

Answer (score 1):

Just for curiosity, an O(1) method for summing squares of the nth numbers.

```
def sum_of_squares( n ):
    return n*(n+1)*(2*n+1)//6
```

Source: https://trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/series/sumNaturalSquares.htm

Answer (score 1):

Here's two solutions in Python that I haven't seen anywhere yet.

```
#list comprehension o(n)
def sum_of_squares1(start, end):
    return sum([n*n for n in range(start, end+1)])

#o(1) maths: Sum(s to e) = sum(1 to e) - sum(1 to (s-1))
def formula(n):
    return n*(n+1)*(2*n+1)/6

def sum_of_squares2(start, end):
    return formula(end)-formula(start-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok stored in a list:

```
sum_of_squares=[]

def add_squares(start, end,sum_of_squares):
   for n in range(start, end):
       calc=(n**2)
       sum_of_squares.append(calc)
       answer=sum(sum_of_squares)
   print(answer)

add_squares(1,21,sum_of_squares)
```

Result
2870

Comment: lets say 1-5, I want to add.       "1*2 + 2*2 + 3*2 + 4*2 + 5*2"

Comment: just want a sum of all the squares between 1-20.